# How did Billy Batson know about the Seven Sins?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, shazam

In the movie ***Shazam!*** Billy Batson tells Dr. Sivanna the names of all Seven Deadly Sins. He also speaks about the appearance of Envy and other sins.

How did he come to know about the name and character of the sins? When was the knowledge about the sins passed to him as we know that he is not a Superhero geek?

Comment: with the wisdom of Solomon granted to him as part of him powers?

Comment: @mgh42 +1 for your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The seven deadly sins have nothing to do with superheroes, they have been talked about in the real world by Christian thinkers since at least the 4th century CE.

They appear in “The Parson’s Tale” in Chaucer’s *Canterbury Tales*, which many students are required to read and discuss in schools. That’s just one possible way he might have learned about them.

Comment: What about the appearance of them

Comment: @ToddWilcox  You may be right,mostly , but I'm not sure that Billy would be a regular at church

Comment: It's part of Western culture. You don't need to attend church regularly to have heard of them.

Comment: Aren't the seven deadly sins specific to Catholicism? "any Christian church" is not correct here.

Comment: Seems like no one read my last paragraph in the way I meant it so I’ve just deleted it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I did, that's why I added my comment. but if you intended it to mean something different than I anticipated, please add that paragraph back and add a little more explanation to it. I liked your answer

Comment: @OrangeDog in the medieval era may be. I'm a part of western culture and most of my friends, relatives and people I know. but I really doubt that they'd know about this from just being a part of western culture. if it's about god and Satan and Christmas , then you're right. but this deadly sins goes more deeper than that IMO

Comment: I would argue an even stronger form of this answer, that it’s just part of American cultural literacy. I’m actually surprised that so many people seem to think otherwise. Have they really never heard of the concept themselves, or are they from other (non-western) countries? Anyway, if you can’t believe that it’s something people just know because it’s a common cultural reference point (manga and TV show titl s, songs by Lerner and Loewe, the movie “7”, etc), assume that Billy is well-read or that some previous foster family made Billy Batson go to church.

Comment: @Vishwa I'm a third gen atheist and there's nobody in my family who hasn't heard about the 'deadly sins'. It's an incredibly commonly referenced thing across western pop culture, unless you go out of your way to avoid reading books and watching films there's no way you wouldn't have heard of them.

Comment: @Cubic I'm not saying that it's completely unknown, just saying that it's common to know there are deadly sins and number is 7 and sin is a thing that one whouldn't do. but I'm saying about having a deep knowledge, name each sin, having a deep  understanding of each....

Comment: @MichaelStern you may be right, but if we consider behavior of Billy, IMO, he wouldn't bulge. may be for one time, after that, being a teenager and all that "billy",  he'd run away from it, skip it. don't you think? even the most strict family couldn't force him to go to church and sit for the whole sermon every Sunday (or any other day)

Comment: @Vishwa so you're willing to acknowledge that it's common to have heard of them, but the idea that someone might've read up on them on Wikipedia breaks your suspension of disbelief?

Comment: @Cubic I'm not a religious type. so I dunno much about them. but I meant considering Billy. Do you see him as young troubled boy reading on wikipedia about seven deadly sins?